# How to change an android theme programatically only to the snackbar?

Tags: android, styles, themes, snackbar

I want to change the theme of the my custom snackbar

```
public class CustomSnackbar extends BaseTransientBottomBar<CustomSnackbar> {
  public CustomSnackbar(
      CoordinatorLayout parent,
      View contentView,
      BaseTransientBottomBar.ContentViewCallback contentViewCallback) {
    super(parent, contentView, contentViewCallback);
  }
```

i see in the layout it can be set as:

```
   android:theme="@style/Theme.my.WithDarkTextButton"
```

I have tried to set the theme grammatically but found no equivalent:

`contentView.setTheme` is missing. doesn't evey xml attribute can be set via code?

Comment: You can only set the theme on construction, as the third argument (`defStyleAttr`) to the constructor of a View. What are you passing for `contentView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a LayoutInflater, then you have to set the theme in XML.

If you programmatically create a View:

```
View contentView = new View(context);
```

Then change it a little bit:

```
View contentView = new View(new ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.Theme_my_WithDarkTextButton);
```

You can't set the theme on-demand. The View only reads the theme attributes when it's constructed.

Comment: No. There are quite a few that are XML or constructor only.